# How to select layer in the object data instead of selecting the stroke in grease pencil?

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools, grease-pencil, layers

How to select layer in the object data instead of selecting the stroke?
The grease pencil layer cannot be selected either in the outliner or under the object data layer panel.
I tried to lock the other layers so as to isolate the target layer and use [select box] in [edit mode] to select it. I am wondering is there any quick way to select the target layer?

[image]

Comment: what you do + `A` is the only way to select a layer, but the isolate button (next to the lock) makes it a bit faster when you have a lot of layers

Answer (score 0):

Since GP object is only one object you can't select layers individually in Object mode. If you want to do that, you have to separate the layer in Edit mode to make it a distinct object.

Comment: The layers have been separated in the layer in [Edit mode] already, yet there is no response when I mouseClicked the layer.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, selecting Grease Pencil layers is not possible in Object Mode because only object level entities can be selected in Object Mode. However, assuming you have the grease pencil object selected already, if you go into Draw Mode, Edit Mode or Sculpt Mode, you can press <kbd>y</kbd> to bring up a layer selection menu on the fly. This is more convenient than accessing the layers either in the Properties Panel, or in the Grease Pencil context of the Dope Sheet editor.

[image]

Hope this helps.